# Domain  and  exponential  of  self- adjoint  operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let  $A$  be  a  self -  adjoint  operator  on  a Hilbert  space $\mathcal{H}$ and  let  $D(A)$  be  its  domain. If  $\psi \in D(A)$  then  $exp(-itA) \psi \in D(A)$ iff $A$  is  bounded ?

Thank  you guys, sorry  if  the  question  is  too  trivial ! ;)

Physics  beginner

Comment: This question would be better for http://math.stackexchange.com, as it is not really "research level".

Comment: In fact, the implication $\psi \in D(A) \Rightarrow e^{-itA}\psi \in D(A)\ \forall t\in \mathbb R$ is true regardless of boundedness *and* self-adjointness of $A$. You only need that $iA$ generates a group at all, cf. the book of Engel-Nagel.

Answer (score 1):

No. If A is self-adjoint, then exp(-itA) maps D(A) to D(A) regardless whether A is bounded. You should read a text on semigroup theory for linear operators, for instance Pazy's book.

Comment: No semigroup theory is needed here.  Just note that the spectral theorem reduces the question to the case where $\mathcal{H}$ is an $L^2$ space and  $A$ is a multiplication operator.

Comment: The perhaps only interesting thing here is that $\exp(-iA)\psi$ can not be defined by the exponential series for *all* vectors in $D(A)$. One really needs the definition via the spectral calculus, i.e. the integral over the projection valued measure of $A$.